# Android Daily Weekly leaderboard implementation?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

Hi I want to implement leaderboard for my game. I just implemented google play leaderboard. But the question is I want Daily and weekly leaderboard. And I need to reset from google play console daily and weekly.

@Thank you.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can  reset the value in draft leaderboard only , daily/weekly as needed ,
 in the Google Play Console, click the button labeled Reset leader board progress at the bottom of the form for that event.
To reset leaderboard data programmatically, call the Management API Scores methods.

link  https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards